# Sharepoint 2013 deployment issue

Tags: 2010, development, 2013, upgrade

I have created my custom solution in Visual studio 2010 for SharePoint 2010. Now I want to deploy that solution on Sharepoint 2013. How can I deploy that?

When I am deploying my solution through `stsadm` command it is deployed on 14 hive in SharePoint 2013. Now, the problem is that I have created my custom master page through Visual Studio and registered user control on master page, since it is deploy on 14 hive in 2013, when I am accessing a page it shows an error that the user control was not found. This is caused by SharePoint searching for it in the 15 hive.

If at all I am giveng 14 hive reference for registering control in master page it is searching in 15 hive. Is there any way that it can find it in the 14 hive? Or how can I deploy all my webparts and masterpages in the 15 hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the following property:

```
SharePointVersion="15.0"
```

in  element in the manifest file of your project to deploy it to the 15 hive. Otherwise it gets installed into SharePoint 14 location.